# XFBML: <fb:photo> not working?

Tags: fbml, xfbml, photos

Have anyone had any success with this tag?

I'm in the process of converting a FBML app to iframe. Other (X)FBML tags in the same block is rendered correctly, but the  tags is untouched. Is it not supported?

The documentation on FBML/XFBML is really confusing...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use XFBML for that. You can use graph generated url to get picture of any object, just add a "picture" at the end of the graph url like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_ID/picture
```

and add it as a source of your image in your markup. This should work for user's id, photo's id, etc.

hope this helps